# Do I have to use the OpenGL functions via the QOpenGLFunctions class in order to use "Dynamically Loading Graphics Drivers"?

Tags: qopenglfunctions

Do I have to use the OpenGL functions via the QOpenGLFunctions class in order to use "Dynamically Loading Graphics Drivers"? Is QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Compatibility OK?

According to [Dynamically Loading Graphics Drivers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers) from Qt, "When a given environment fails to provide a proper OpenGL 2.0 implementation, it will fall back automatically to ANGLE", AND "The dynamic loading has a significant impact on applications that contain native OpenGL calls: they may fail to link since qmake no longer automatically adds opengl32.lib or libGLESv2.lib. Instead, applications are expected to use the OpenGL functions via the QOpenGLFunctions class". I realized that this means I have to use the OpenGL functions via the QOpenGLFunctions class in order to use "Dynamically Loading Graphics Drivers". But, I want to know "is QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Compatibility OK?"

Edit1:
New functionality in the core OpenGL 4.1 specification includes:
Full compatibility with OpenGL ES 2.0 APIs for easier porting between mobile and desktop platforms;
The above is from the opengl official website: https://www.khronos.org/news/press/opengl-4-1-released

So, QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Compatibility must be full compatibility with OpenGL ES 2.0 APIs.
Is my understanding correct?